# Object is currently in use elsewhere - when image.save

Tags: c#, wpf

[image] Using the following code, we got the error 'Object is currently in use elsewhere'

```
private void CaptureDone(System.Drawing.Bitmap e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.pictureBox.Image = e;
                 if (isSending)
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendVideoBuffer), pictureBox.Image);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

     void SendVideoBuffer(object bufferIn)
            {
    TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[0].ToString(), 6000);
                           NetworkStream ns = tcp.GetStream();
                           if (ns != null)
                           {
                               System.Drawing.Image buffer = (System.Drawing.Image)bufferIn;
                               buffer.Save(ns, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);// error comes here
                               ns.Close();
                               tcp.Close();
                            }
           }
```

Please give suggestions.

Comment: where is `bufferIn` defined? always a good idea to use `using` block when dealing with `streams`.

Comment: @Mayank BufferIn is an object. code updated. Please check

Comment: @Mayank - Still having the same error

Comment: @Mayank - please check the image uploaded

Comment: can you please post the part of the code that call's `SendVideoBuffer(object)`?

Comment: @Mayank: i posted that u asked....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13336/discussion-between-anoop-mohan-and-mayank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDI+ images are not thread safe, you need to aquire lock on the object.

```
void SendVideoBuffer(object bufferIn) 
    { 

 var tcp = new TcpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[0].ToString(), 6000); 
                   var ns = tcp.GetStream(); 
                   if (ns != null) 
                   { 
                       var buffer = (System.Drawing.Image)bufferIn;
                       lock(buffer) 
                            buffer.Save(ns, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                       ns.Close(); 
                       tcp.Close(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: `if(picturebox.InvokeRequired) { pictureBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker( () => SendVideoBuffer(picturebox.Image))); } else SendVideoBuffer(picturebox.Image);`

Comment: this is the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such exception before and have more foundings on it.

Most of the reasons for this exception is caused by multi-thread, where we try to operate a same one global image.

Here is a good explain why this exception happens: "With WinForms, this generally means there is a recursive Graphics.GetHdc occurring.  GetHdc must match a ReleaseHdc before any other GetHdc.  Recursive means you have something like GetHdc->GetHdc->ReleaseHdc->ReleaseHdc, instead of GetHdc->ReleaseHdc->GetHdc->ReleaseHdc.  Another possibility is that there is a missing call to ReleaseHdc. (i.e. GetHdc->GetHdc->ReleaseHdc)".

Deep into the image.Save method more, it will call GetHdc->ReleaseHdc pair method. Also, I guess if we try to get image.width or image.Clone methods, it also will call GetHdc method.

So, be careful when try to use a global image in threads. Most of the operations are not thread safe.